# How to limit number of objects with same attribute via validation on update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a Object in Ruby on Rails3 which should not exist more than three times with the same date.
I have no problem on validating the object on creation, but what happens when an existing object gets updated and becomes the fourth object of a day?

I tried to hook in the validation at before_save, after_save, after_update etc. none did work...

Thanks guys!

Here is my current validation:

```
class Dish < ActiveRecord::Base
before_create :creation_validaton
after_save :update_validaton


def creation_validaton
  if Dish.find(:all,:conditions => ["date = ?",self.date]).count > 2
    errors.add(:date, "more than 3 a day")
    return false
  else
    return true
  end 
end

def update_validaton
   if Dish.find(:all,:conditions => ["date = ?",self.date]).count > 3
     errors.add(:date, "more than 3 a day!")
     return false 
   else
     return true
   end 
 end
end
```

Comment: How are you setting the date field?

Comment: It's not totally clear what the problem is. What is not working exactly? What result do you expect and what are you seeing instead?

Comment: shouldn't `after_save` be `before_update`. But anyways, you should handle validations in validation step and not save step.

Answer (score 2):

Some kind of this. I didn't test it

```
class CountPerDayValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    count = record.class.where(attribute => value).count
    record.errors[attribute] << "more than  #{options[:max]} for #{attribute}" if count >= options[:max]
  end
end

class Dish < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :date, :count_per_day => {:max => 3}
end
```